# jQuery selector re-use best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When storing a DOM object as a variable, which is the best practice use of that variable:

```js
// Option 1

var myElement1 = $(".container").find('ul li:eq(1)');
$(myElement1).css('background', 'red');


// Option 2

var myElement2 = $(".container").find('ul li:eq(2)');
myElement2.css('background', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

It seems like I have seen it both ways, and as you can see, they both do the job. Options 1 seems a little redundant to me, but I just wanted to check before committing Option 2 to my personal style.

Comment: Yep, option one is redundant, since `myElement1` is already a jQuery object

Comment: Do both not return jQuery Objects?  If so, it wouldn't matter if you wrapped it in additional parens.  As a side-note:  I always like to label in javascript, variables that are jQuery objects as `var $myElement1` with the dollar sign to remember it is in fact a jQuery object.  Since we are talking about best practice and all...

Comment: I always store jQuery objects prefixed with a '$', so option 2 with $myElement2. It makes it easier to keep track of.

Comment: They use option 1 not like you've shown it, but when they do something inside a function, which they want to accept both jquery object and htmlelement. Nobody writes code exctly like option 1, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option is completely valid and good practice, however the first makes no sense. You're trying to jQueryify an object which has already been jQueryified. It basically is something like `$($("body"))`.

Also note that it's good practice to prepend `$` to variables which contains jQuery object. Your code should look like this:

```
var $myElement2 = $(".container").find('ul li:eq(2)');
$myElement2.css('background', 'blue');
```

As @Terry wrote, the most optimized way would be:

```
var $c = $(".container ul li");
var $second = $c.eq(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the first case is redundant, and actually takes longer to execute (albeit not by a whole lot)

You can see this in the snippet here:

```js
var s = window.performance.now();

var myElement1 = $(".container").find('ul li:eq(1)');
$(myElement1).css('background', 'red');

var e = window.performance.now();
console.log(e - s);

s = window.performance.now();

var myElement2 = $(".container").find('ul li:eq(2)');
myElement2.css('background', 'blue');

e = window.performance.now();
console.log(e - s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It's giving me about a 2 to 3 millisecond difference in speed.

I'd stick with the second option as it's cleaner and faster.